# Query regarding covalent bonding

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds

Why don't covalent bonds result in the atoms involved in the bond being charged?
Let's take the Chlorine/Cl2 molecule as an example.
So each Chlorine atom in the Cl2 molecule has 7 valence electrons. Each Chlorine atom contributes 1 electron to the covalent bond; thus, 2 electrons are shared between the two chlorine atoms in the molecule and each Chlorine atom has a complete octet. The shared pair of electrons belong to both Chlorine atoms, meaning that each Chlorine atom has 18 electrons and 17 protons which is 1 more electron than the total number of protons. This implies that each chlorine atom has a net -1 charge.
However, the Cl2 molecule has 34 electrons and 34 protons, implying that it doesn't have a net charge.

Why has such a contradiction arisen?

Can someone help explain this?

Comment: The charges do arise in covalent bonds due to different electronegativities in case of heteronuclear molecules and oscillating electron cloud in homonuclear molecule but those charges are very slight and always complimentary for the two atoms meaning that partial charges created are equal and opposite due to which overall molecule is neutral.

Comment: @Pscionexam2003 It's not a question about partial charges, but about electron counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction.

From both shared electrons, each chlorine atom "owns" one half.

$$17 = 16 + \frac 12 + \frac 12$$

If a husband and his wife share their family car, they do not have two cars, do they? Each of them has one half, together one car.

---

The theory of molecular orbitals considers forming 2 molecular orbitals (bonding and antibonding) as the linear combination of original atomic orbitals. The one with lower energy (bonding orbital) is filled by the electron pair, each electron from the respective atom.

This bonding orbital is shared between both chlorine atoms.

---

For your case, there is need to distinguish "having" as inventory and "having" as quantum feature/functionality.

In context of inventory, each atoms has 17 electrons.

In context of functionality, each atom has 18 electrons, as 2 electrons are servants of 2 lords. They occupy the bonding molecular orbital, stretched over both chlorine atom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my query is a bit different...After the formation of the bond between the 2 chlorine atoms,2 electrons are shared between the two. This means that each chlorine atom has an extra electron as the shared pair of electrons are not "owned" by any one atom, they belong to both. If each chlorine atom were to "own" after bond formation one-half of the shared electrons then each Chlorine atom would have an incomplete octet. Am I missing something?

Comment: If 1 electron belongs to 2 atoms, each has effectively 1/2. It is like in CsCl ionic lattice, where each Cs+ is surrounded by 8 Cl- ions. But each Cl- ion is shared between 8 such crystallographic cells, so Cs+ ion "owns" 1/8 of it. And 8 times 1/8 is 1. / See also the answer update.

Comment: If the bonding orbital is filled by 2 electrons donated by each Chlorine atom in the Cl2 molecule and is shared between both chlorine atoms then doesn't each chlorine atom effectively get only 1 electron as a result of which both the atoms have an incomplete octet which in reality I suppose isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer update...I get your point. What I don't understand is why the covalently bonded chlorine atoms which should have a complete octet that is 8 electrons in the valence shell possess a net charge of -1. I know that the number of protons and electrons in the Chlorine molecule are equal and therefore it should be electrically neutral and therefore should not possess a net charge.

Comment: They do not possess a net charge. From 2 x 17 electrons, 2 X 16 are around their Cl atom and remaining 2 are around both atoms. Thinking there is net negative change (each atom claiming bot for itself) has no bigger reason than net positive charge (each atom giving it up for the other one.// By other words, 2 electrons extended their spheres of interest to both atoms.